# check if webView can login

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I'm making an app where users uses a custom view to login into a website. I got everything working, from passing the data from UITextFields to webView website, also i can submit the login and username using this code

```
NSString *performSubmitJS = @"var passFields = document.querySelectorAll(\"input[type='submit']\"); \
passFields[1].click()";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:performSubmitJS];
```

How can I check if the user introduced wrong username and password? is there anyway to use something like

```
document.querySelectorAll
```

to check if user introduced wrong credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your webpage reloads when you click the login button, which means you want to define this delegate method if you haven't already:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView;
```

and you'll need to re-inject your javascript here to scan the page for some indication that an invalid password has been entered. You can use querySelector for this but you'll have to inspect the webpage for the bad password case and find an element that is uniquely displayed for bad passwords. It might be easier to just check something like `if(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf('invalid password') > -1) window.location = 'WRONG_PASSWORD'` (replace 'invalid password' with whatever the webpage says when you enter an invalid password) and you can implement:

```
- (BOOL)WebView:(UIWebView *)myWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request;
```

and check to see if the URL ever equals `WRONG_PASSWORD` to know if the user entered a wrong password and react to it in objc.

Comment: I think this way should be easier, check this please and let me know. thanks
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725909/pass-alert-from-uiwebview-to-ios-app
@Macmee