# pass alert from UIWebView to iOS app

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I have create an app, which works fine. The only thing i need is to pass the alerts from uiwebview to my iOS app.

i have this alert on my uiwebview

```
<div id="alerts" class="alerts">

<p class="alert-red">ok. come back again tomorrow, not now.</p>
```

i want this alert to transfer into my app and make it into an uialertview

```
UIAlertView *errr = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"nil" message:@"ok. come back again tomorrow, not now." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok, Got it" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errr show];
```

any idea how to achieve this result? do i need NSNotification to listen when this alert show up on uiwebview?

I tried something like this

```
NSString *theTitle=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"var targetDiv = document.getElementById('alerts').getElementsByClassName('alert-red')[0];"];

NSLog(@"%@",theTitle);
```

So I can try to retrieve that message from "alert-red" but doesn't work.

I'm new to javascript and html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is the typical workaround](http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2008/08/14/calling-objective-c-from-javascript-in-an-iphone-uiwebview/) used to solve this problem:

in your webpage when you want to show this alert, run this javascript code:

`window.location = 'custom_action';`

then in objc implement `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` on your controller (and set `yourWebView.delegate = yourController`)

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
       shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
       navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  // detect when the webview switches to this custom url
  if([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString: @"custom_action"]) {
    UIAlertView *errr = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"nil" message:@"ok. come back again tomorrow, not now." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok, Got it" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [errr show];
    // this prevents the webview from actually trying to load the custom url
    return NO;
  }
  // allow the url to load if its not your custom url
  return YES;
}
```